# Doubling letters of a string in java

Tags: java, eclipse, string, loops, for-loop

I was asked to write a method that was passed a String and then return a String with each character doubled. I found the code on a previously asked question, but what I was wondering is why the s.charAt(i) had to be added twice.

The code I used was:

```
    public static String twoChars(String s){
    String r= "";
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
            r=r+s.charAt(i)+s.charAt(i);
    return r;
    }
```

Comment: What does "doubled" mean to you?

Comment: For short strings, string addition doesn't matter much, but it still hurts my eyes when characters are added in a loop instead of being inserted with a (pre-initialized) `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @JamesKPolk thanks! I don't know how I missed that, I'm just starting programming and loops really confuse me. P.S. Love your username

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the program logic, you will see that the following occurs:

```
1) pass a string (for example "hello")
2) start another empty string (String r = "")
3) when i==0, r becomes: ""+ h + h
4) when i==1, r becomes: hh + e + e
5) etc.
6) return "hheelloo"
```

**NOTE**: As was stated previously, using StringBuilder is a much better solution because strings are immutable (each time r is changed, a new string is created and thus wasting precious resources).

Answer (score 0):

Because r is empty, The method adds each char twice to r before returns it. a better approach is to use StringBuilder for that :

```
public static String twoChars(String s){
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
            sb.append(s.charAt(i)+ "" +s.charAt(i));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: `s.charAt(i)+ "" +s.charAt(i)` will still create many strings, which defeats the purpose of the use of `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

Well here's how to think about this and what to keep in mind.

First of all, `String` in Java is immutable. All modifications you are doing on a `String` will result in a new `String` being created. This may be a problem if you do a lot of modifications on a lot of strings, resulting in a massive memory usage. Always remember this, especially when you have loops where you change strings.

Now back to the problem. Given a `String`, `s`, you want to "double" every single character. Since you'll have to check every single character of `s`, you will probably need a loop.

What else do you need? Well, you need some sort of structure to build your new `String`. You can go either for `StringBuilder` or `char[]`. A `StringBuilder` does just that: builds strings. However, it builds then in a memory-efficient way. Actually internally it contains a `char[]`.

Here's the `StringBuilder` solution:

```
String input = "hello";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.length() * 2);

for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
{
    builder.append(input.charAt(i)).append(input.charAt(i));
}

String finalString = builder.toString();
```

Here's a `char[]` solution

```
String input = "hello";

char[] tempChar = new char[input.length() * 2];

for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
{
    tempChar[2 * i] = input.charAt(i);
    tempChar[2 * i + 1] = input.charAt(i);
}

String output = new String(tempChar);
```